# Div element bring out from div parent?

Tags: html, css

I working on a project and i have little problem with the div,
the scenario below:-

```
section.portfolio
  .flex.flex--center
    .col-1
      .img-strip
    .col-1.order-first
      p.home-lead.outdented Lore ipsum 
      a(href="#").home-cta See More
```

http://codepen.io/alb_dev/pen/KaxMVv

I have put in codepen you can see the problem i have:

1. The pink div i want to put side to the div who have text and the button element
   [i want to put the file like this on the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVwyp.png)

but when i put the div pink in:-

```
.img-strip
    position: absolute
        background:pink
        top: 0
        margin: -50px 0
        width: 100%
        height:100%
```

and the div parent in  :-

```
position:relative
```

the div in pink disappear you can see on codepen i have post.

> Hope i have explained well my problem if not please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed` instead of `position:absolute`

Comment: i have make the position: fixed nothing change only the div become bigger

Comment: Show the sketch, what are you looking for?

Comment: see the image i have posted

Comment: this is the best answer you got from me. if you don't know how html,css works( position, float, fluid design). you always will be in ocean of problem.

Comment: for this i ask for help because i don't understand why the  position goes like this

Answer (score 0):

There are some basic problems with the structure of the code. Since you already have a grid-system in place using the method you are is not recommended. So from what I could understand of your problem, the following is the solution.

**HTML** *old*

```
<div class="col-1">
    <div class="img-strip"></div>
</div>
```

**HTML** 
*new*

```
<div class="col-1 img-strip">
```

**CSS** *old*

```
section.portfolio .img-strip {
  position: absolute;
  background: pink;
  top: 0;
  margin: -50px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% + 100px);
}
```

**CSS** *new*

```
section.portfolio .img-strip {
    background: pink;
    width: 320px; /* Depending on what width you want col-1 has a maximum width if 320px */
    height: 200px;
}
```